# Find all $\alpha$ such that for any $x>-1$ we have $\ln(1+x)\leq x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\alpha x^3$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

Here's a small problem I'm trying to solve:

Find all $\alpha$ such that for any $x>-1$ we have $\ln(1+x)\leq x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\alpha x^3$

After moving some things to the left side we have:

$$\frac{\ln(1+x)-x+\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^3}\leq \alpha$$

So there's a function on $x$ on the right and a constant function on the right. Which means, if I'm understanding this correctly, that we're looking for a horizontal line, that will lie higher than the plot of $\frac{\ln(1+x)-x+\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^3}$ function on xy-axis. But WolframAlpha tells me that: $\lim_{x\rightarrow -1} \frac{\ln(1+x)-x+\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^3} = +\infty$ which would mean such $\alpha$  doesn't exist. Is it really the case here?

Comment: When you divide by $x^3$, the inequality changes direction. (as long as $x\to-1$ )

Comment: When you have $\frac{\ln(1+x)-x+(x^2/2)}{x^3}\le \alpha$, you suppose that $x^3\gt 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function
$$g_\alpha(x):=x-{x^2\over2}+\alpha x^3-\log(1+x)=\left(\alpha-{1\over3}+o(1)\right)x^3\qquad(x\to0)\ .$$
It follows that $g_\alpha$ changes sign at $x=0$ unless $\alpha={1\over3}$. Therefore $\alpha={1\over3}$ is a necessary condition for the desired inequality to hold. For $g:=g_{1/3}$ one has $g(0)=g'(0)=0$, and an easy computation gives
$$g''(x)=x^2{3+2x\over(1+x)^2}\geq0\qquad(x>-1)\ .$$
It follows that $g$ is convex on its domain, whence the line $y=0$ is a supporting line of the graph. In other words: $g(x)\geq0$ for all $x>-1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Dividing by $x^3$ you actually have to consider two different cases. If $x>0$ indeed you get  $$\frac{\ln(1+x)-x+\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^3}\le\alpha \tag{1}$$ but if $x<0$ you get $$\frac{\ln(1+x)-x+\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^3}\ge\alpha.\tag{2}$$ Let $f(x)$ be defined by the LHS of $(1)$ and $(2)$ and $L=\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)$. Once you show that $f$ is decreasing on $(-1,+\infty)$, it follows that only $\alpha= L$ satisfies your inequality.