# Find all real a for which the following is true for all $x > -1$, $ ln(1+x) < x -\frac{ x^2}{2} + ax^3$

Tags: taylor-expansion

Find all real a for which the following is true for all $x >-1 $, ${ln(1+x) }< x -\frac{ x^2}{2} + ax^3$

the question is pretty much as mentioned above. I figured out that the expression is true for $a \ge 1/3$ and is not true for $a < 0$, but I'm not sure what happens for $0 < a < 1/3$.

Comment: We had a similar question a day ago; see  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1275354/find-all-alpha-such-that-for-any-x-1-we-have-ln1x-leq-x-fracx22/1275752#1275752    Note that there is no $a\in{\mathbb R}$ such that the strong inequaltiy holds true for all $x>-1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\log(1+x)-x+\frac{x^2}{2}=\int_{0}^{x}\left(\frac{1}{1+t}-1+t\right)\,dt = \int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^2}{1+t}\,dt $$
and assuming $x\in(0,1)$ we have:
$$\log(1+x)-x+\frac{x^2}{2}\geq\frac{1}{1+x}\int_{0}^{x}t^2\,dt = \frac{x^3}{3(1+x)}$$
so the inequality cannot hold in a right neighbourhood of zero if $a\in\left(0,\frac{1}{3}\right)$.